# Are there any risks in Python if the module name and class name from inside had identical names?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I would like to know if there any risks to use the exact same name for module and a class from inside the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that modules should have short, all-lowercase names, while class names use the CapWords convention. So, if you have the same name for a module and a class, you're not following those style conventions.

Technically, there's no risk at all.

Comment: You are perfectly right, but if the module is an acronym and somebody decided to use uppercase you endup with somethign like `ABC` for both module and class.

Comment: Well, even then the module should have a lowercase name. A good example is [collections.abc](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.abc.html) from Python 3.3+. But of course, the style guide is just a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from potentially confusing yourself (or other devs), I don't see anything wrong with it. In fact, there are several examples of this in the standard Python modules e.g. `random.random` and `pprint.pprint`.

*p.s. to be pedantic `random` and `pprint` are functions rather than classes, but the risks would be equivalent should there be any*

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem. An example from standard lib: `time.time` is a function with the same name as the enclosing module.

I probably can't give you a class example from stdlib because they have names like MyClass as per the "Class Names" section of [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), while module names tend to be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on how you import the module. If you just import the file and not the class , then I guess it would be something like

> myModule.myModule.function()

which doesn't seem so desirable. if you use

> from myModule import *

then you would use like

> myModule.function()